# jQuery Cycle - pagerAnchorBuilder with background-image from div

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have made a jquery Cycle with Div's

```
<div id="slideshow2">
  <div style="background: url(images/1.jpg) center center;"></div>
  <div style="background: url(images/2.jpg) center center;"></div>
  <div style="background: url(images/3.jpg) center center;"></div>
</div>
```

Now i try to realise Thumbnails.

```
$('#slideshow2').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  '2000',
slideResize: 0,
pager:  '#nav', 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {      
   return '<li><div style="' + slide.style.background + '"></div></li>';
}
```

});

It's dont work.

If i wrote:

```
return '<li>' + slide.style.background + '</li>';
```

without divs - it show's me what i want:

```
<li class="">url("images/1.jpg") repeat scroll center center transparent</li>
```

but if i use 
It Show's:

```
<li class=""><div transparent"="" center="" scroll="" repeat="" 1.jpg")="" images="" style="url("></div></li>
```

Can someone help me

Comment: inspect your element with firbug.I am sure you will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="">url("images/1.jpg") repeat scroll center center transparent</li>
```

The answer is here. You output will be:

```
<li><div style="url("images/1.jpg") repeat scroll center center transparent"></div></li>
```